# Catan Seafarers - The Forgotten Tribe scenario : Who claims the harbor?

Tags: catan-seafarers

We have a player who has moved a ship near to a harbor and has claimed the harbor. But, we have another player who is gonna place a settlement for first time on the same island.

So, in this case who will have the final claim and use of the harbor on the new island?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the rules : 
[Catan Seafarers Game Rules and Scenarios](http://www.catan.com/en/download/?Seafarers_rv_Rules_091907.pdf)

> Harbors
>
> If you build (or move) a ship on an edge next to a harbor, you take
>   the harbor. If you have a settlement on the coast, you must
>   immediately place the harbor on an adjacent edge. However, harbors
>   must never occupy adjacent or the same edges. In case you have no
>   appropriate coastal settlement, you can put the harbor aside until
>   such a settlement is built. When you have placed a harbor, you can use
>   it immediately, even during the same turn.

**Interpretation.** This means that the first player who places or builds a ship next to a harbor, physically picks up the harbor, i.e. removes it from the board. The player will then place this harbor on an edge next to one of his/her coastal settlements **on the main island**, if the player has one. No one can build a settlement on any of the small islands.

«So, in this case who will have the final claim and use of the harbor on the new island?»

The player who moved next to the harbor claims it (picks it up) and gets to place the harbor next to one of his/her coastal settlements, immediately, or later.

«But, we have another player who is gonna place a settlement for first time on the same island.»

> During play, no settlement can be built on the surrounding small
>   islands that do not produce resources.

For the harbor, it's first come, first served. And, no player can build a settlement on any of the small islands.

Comment: Thank you. The two if statements (without mention of move to main island) in the rule confused us lot.